# Laravel 5.6 Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.6 I've tried to upload my website to 000webhost
In my localhost everything works fine but when I try to access the website from 000webhost I get this error

Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
Array to string conversion (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = e@example.com limit 1)
what might be the problem?

Here in an example:

[image]

Comment: it give output in array and you are trying get value in string so that is exception

Comment: It works fine while I'm using xampp

Comment: This is not a completed question. I can't help. :D

Comment: It's your settings in database.php. Try adding this in the mysql array  'options'  => array(
               PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
           ) Warning: this will return all your integers as strings in collections. Why not use a VPS? Or if you want to show a demo just use valet? And the actual problem comes from the mysql library on the server. I guess it's a shared hosting so nothing you can so about it

Comment: Check your env file to make sure your DB_HOST, DB_PORT and DB_DATABASE values are correct.

Comment: Thank you so much Indra ^_^ you just saved my life it works :)